# How to use Rails 4 root path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

According to https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8468 and http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/dynamic-index-html-rails-4-countdown-to-2013 it is not necessary to remove the index.html file in order to use the root path in Rails 4.

However, the following renders the public/index.html file without hitting the controller:

Routes file:

```
root :to => 'pages#index'
```

Controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts :index
  end
end
```

Using a Welcome controller has the same behavior.

So, do you have to delete the public/index.html file to use the root path?

Rails 4.1.6

Answer (score 2):

Well, a brand new Rails 4.1.6 app won't have any `public/index.html` file to delete, so if you have a `public/index.html` file (maybe because the app was created with a previous version of Rails) then yes, you'll need to remove it before Rails will serve the dynamic root path.